# Perl script to get the first element of arrays passed as reference

Tags: arrays, perl

I want to call a subroutine by passing around 4 arrays to it and then get the first value of each array and then create a new array(array of first elements of arrays that are passed) in the subroutine and then return back that array. Here is the code I tried with

```
my @a = (97,34,6,7);
my @b = ("A", "B", "F", "D");
my @c = (5..15);
my @d = (1..10);
my @tailings = popmany ( \@a, \@b, \@c, \@d );

print @tailings;

sub popmany {
    my @retlist = ();
    for my $aref (@_) {            #1
        my $arrele = @$aref;       #2
        push @retlist , $arrele    #3
    }
    return @retlist;
}
```

Here in  #1 I use a loop and get the first array , then in line 2 I assign the whole array to a variable, thinking that by default the perl will only store the first variable of array into @arrele.  the I push  the  $arrele to a new array  @retlist  , Sorry I dint refer any notes, so my procedure might be wrong. But this is throwing me a output like
    441110

which has no sense.

Please explain me the code how can I do that.

Comment: `popmany` as a name is doubly misleading. `pop` *removes* the *last* element of an array and returns it. This returns the *first* value without altering the arrays.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's here:

```
my $arrele = @$aref;
```

where you're asking perl to put `@{$aref}` into scalar context, which returns the length (number of elements in) the array pointed at by $aref.

Instead try:

```
my $arrele = $aref->[0];
```

which will access the first element of the array instead.

Comment: Thanks ...  Can you tell me why  my $arrele = $aref[0];  doesn't work ?

Comment: Because $aref is an array ref and you're trying to access it as an array. Try `@$aref[0]` instead if you desperately want to avoid `$aref->[0]` which is a lot clearer.

Comment: $aref[0] means "first element of array @aref" but $aref is a scalar containing a reference to some other array, so you need to use -> to dereference it first.

Comment: `$$aref[0]` is also a viable option.

Comment: I thought I wrote that in the comment above, but looking at it again, I see that I've accidentally used a one element array slice. :$

Answer (score 6):

The line

```
my $arrele = @$aref;
```

assigns the length of the `@$aref` array to `$arrele`. To get the first element of the array you could use any of:

```
my $arrele = $$aref[0];
my $arrele = $aref->[0];    
my ($arrele) = @$aref;  # note the parenthesis which create list context
```

Also, since you generate a list based on another list, you could use `map`:

```
sub popmany {
    return map $_->[0], @_;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sub popmany { 
    my @retlist = (); 
    for my $aref (@_) { #1 
        my $arrele = @$aref[0]; #2 
        push @retlist , $arrele#3 
    } 
    return @retlist; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Far more simply written as

```
  sub popmany 
  {
    map $_->[0], @_;
  }
```

Comment: Please leave simple code to codegolf questions. Easy code is the way to go, and this is not the easy way.